# cs0103: The name 'input' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, readline

I was doing the project for methods on Codecademy and was having trouble saving a ReadLine input into a variable and use it in a switch case statement. I tried my best to look up the issue but couldn't figure it out myself. I'm an absolute beginner, so please forgive me if this is trivial or has been answered before.

The relevant section of my code looks as  follows:

---

```
public static void CalculateTotalCost()
{
  retry:
  Console.Write("What monument would you like to have calculated? (Teotihuacan, Taj Mahal or Great Mosque): ");
  input = Console.ReadLine();

  switch(input)
  {
    case "Teotihuacan":
    break;
    case "Taj Mahal":
    break;
    case "Great Mosque":
    break;
    default:
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong entry, try again.");
    goto retry;
  }
}
```

---

My best guess was to declare my variable 'input' as a string but weirdly enough codecademy would crash every time i tried saving my code that way.

Comment: use anything other than goto statements. When you declare input as string, whats the exception?

Comment: The solution _is_ to declare input as string. If the environment crashes if you do that, and if a basic C# tutorial teaches you `goto`, find a different one.

Comment: @Bongert You should refactor for example by using a loop, and why not a local or class method to decouple the conditioned retry looping and the processing.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the beginning of your method from:

```
public static void CalculateTotalCost()
{
  retry:
```

to:

```
public static void CalculateTotalCost()
{
  string input;
  retry:
```

Also, please don't use `goto`.

There are much better ways.

Try using a loop:

```
string name = null;

while (name == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter meaningful information");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (input)
    {
        case "Teotihuacan":
            name = input;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"You selected: {name}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared the input variable.

Do it by

```
string input;
```

And then use it.

Or

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Didnt get your point?

Comment: Yes, it compiles in c# as it assigns the input from the console to the input element and then uses it